# Salesforce Community Loading Balls Hanging

Tags: community, community-builder

I'm building a community page and am making use of Salesforce's built-in menu navigation. When I navigate to a new page, Salesforce's three loading balls (pictured) show up and hang. They won't go away unless I refresh the page. I've tried to override the loading div's CSS to no avail. Anyone have any advice or experience with this issue? [image: Loading Balls]

Comment: Can you inspect element in browser and verify if there is any message in console?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment and this is not an conclusive answer...

I have the same issue and can't find any solution and i would like to know why this happend.

Anyway, I temporaly fixed the issue hiding the loading balls modifiyng the css. (Theme tab -> Modify CSS)

```
.siteforceLoadingBalls {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.mask{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

This hide that annoying loading balls and the site works normally.

In my case it only happens when i click in the currently page menu button, for example, I'm in Home page and click in home menu button.

this is not the most elegant solution, is there anyone that know why this happend? please help, the console don't show any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I removed `{!v.body}` element from the page payout and Loading balls started to remain, blocking the page. While playing around I put `{!v.body}` element back and it helped!